# How to fail an akka promise?

Tags: scala, akka, future

Suppose I have a function like this (I use akka 2.0.2):

```
def foo(message: String): Future[SomeClass] =
  for {
    result <- actor ? message
  } yield SomeClass(result)
```

The caller of a function sets `onSuccess` and `onFailure` hooks on the future, so if I want an actor to break the promise, I make it send `akka.actor.Status.Failure` back to the sender. That works just fine. Now, what if I want to check some condition in `foo` and return the failed future in case condition fails/succeeds?

```
def foo(message: String): Future[SomeClass] =
  if(...) {
    ...//return failed future
  } else {
    for {
      result <- actor ? message
    } yield SomeClass(result)
  }
```

What the 'return failed future' block should be like? And do I need an execution context to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just return an expression: `Promise.failed(new Exception)`, where the exception is the one you want to fail the future with. You don't need an execution context if you are using the Scala futures and promises in the [Scala standard library from 2.10](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/milestone/scala/concurrent/Promise%24.html).

[Akka futures and promises](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/dispatch/Promise%24.html) require an implicit execution context for the `failed` promise method. There should be a default execution context available in the [execution context companion object](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0/akka/dispatch/ExecutionContext%24.html), which you can use given that you have an `ActorSystem` instance available.